# ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE on IPv6

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, ipv6, cdn

I'm having an issue at some coffee shops that use comcast wifi. These shop only allow ipv6 and it's causing websites to not load with the error ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE. Some websites work (google.com, gmail.com, etc.) and others fail (BBC.com, reddit.com, etc.)

Let's focus on BBC.com

I can get the IP address

```
C:\Users\uname>nslookup bbc.com
Server:  cdns01.comcast.net
Address:  2001:558:feed::1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    bbc.com
Addresses:  2a04:4e42:400::81
          2a04:4e42:600::81
          2a04:4e42::81
          2a04:4e42:200::81
```

But using curl returns does not work for the failing websites

```
C:\Users\uname>curl -v -6 https://www.bbc.com
* Could not resolve host: www.bbc.com
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.bbc.com


C:\Users\uname>curl -6 https://www.google.com
<!doctype html>
.
.
.</html>
C:\Users\uname>
```

Connecting directly to the IP works

```
C:\Users\uname>curl -v -H "Host: www.bbc.com" -k -g -6 "https://[2a04:4e42:600::81]"
*   Trying [2a04:4e42:600::81]:443...
* Connected to 2a04:4e42:600::81 (2a04:4e42:600::81) port 443 (#0)
...
```

It looks like a DNS problem but I've tried manually setting the DNS to google, flushed DNS cache, and got the same problem. Is the ISP (Comcast) or CDN (Fastly) intercepting DNS queries regardless of the chosen DNS provider? This seems concerning.

Comment: As you know bbc.com and www.bbc.com are different domains and I relaized that some known public DNS servers do not return any ipv6 results for www.bbc.com

[link](https://www.nslookup.io/domains/www.bbc.com/dns-records/)